# Why a small network (<2k parameters) exceed the limit of Keras optimizer?

Tags: tensorflow, optimization, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I'm working on a very small model with less than 2K parameters:

```
Model: "model"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input1 (InputLayer)            [(None, 4, 5562, 10)  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense (Dense)                   (None, 4, 5562, 64)  704         input1 [0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)                 (None, 4, 5562, 16)  1040        dense[0][0]                      
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)                 (None, 4, 5562, 1)   17          dense_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
reshape (Reshape)               (None, 4, 5562)      0           dense_2[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
input2 (InputLayer)             [(None, 4, 5562)]    0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
CustomOp(CustomOp)              (None, 4, 5562)      0           reshape[0][0]                    
                                                                 input2 [0][0]                              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
output (Cropping1D)             (None, 1, 5562)      0           CustomOp[0][0]                      
==================================================================================================
Total params: 1,761
Trainable params: 1,761
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
```

But when I train this model, it constantly report error: `BiasGrad requires tensor size <= int32 max`

> InvalidArgumentError: BiasGrad requires tensor size <= int32 max
> [[{{node training/Adam/gradients/gradients/dense/BiasAdd_grad/BiasAddGrad}}]]

I'm sure that the model is correct, because when I reduce the neutron number, it works fine.

I'm very surprised that how could such a small network exceed the limit of Keras optimizer. Could anyone give me some advice?

Comment: I think we need more information, it is not possible to guess this from just the model summary. Reproducible code would be best

Comment: Thanks Dr. Snoopy. My custom layer code is too large to copy. But the custom layer requires all tensor in the batch to calculate. I think maybe this cause the problem. If batchsize = 2K, the max tensor shape is (2K, 4, 5562, 64) , it larger than int32.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error refers to the number of elements in a tensor being greater than the max int32 value, not a memory error related to the number of weights. If your dimensions are correct and nothing in your custom layer generates a massive tensor, reducing your batch size should resolve the problem.